# Variable substitution in GitHub actions workflow

Tags: variables, yaml, environment-variables, github-actions

```html
name: Windows_VM_Creation
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      SUBSCRIPTION:
        description: "Subscription where to Create and deploy the VM"
        required: true
        default: ""        
      REGION:
        description: "Region on which we need to deploy the Image and Create an VM"
        required: true
        default: ""
      ResourceGroupName:
        description: "Enter the Resource Group Name"
        required: true
        default: ""
      OSDiskType:
        description: "Enter the OS Disk type for the VM"
        required: true
        default: ""
      VM_NAME:
        description: "Enter the name of the VM that we are deploying"
        required: true
        default: ""
      VM_SIZE:
        description: "Enter the VM size "
        required: true
        default: ""
      VERSION_NUMBER:
        description: "Enter the version number of the Image"
        required: true
      REGION_CODE:
        description: "Region Code for the OU Path"
        required: true
    
  # Assigning run time values & Secrets into environment variables
env:
  subscription_id: "${{ github.event.inputs.SUBSCRIPTION }}"
  location: "${{ github.event.inputs.REGION }}"
  VM_NAME: "${{ github.event.inputs.VM_NAME }}"
  ResourceGroupName: "${{ github.event.inputs.ResourceGroupName }}"
  NetworkInterfaceName: "${{ github.event.inputs.VM_NAME }}VMNic"
  OSDiskName: "${{ github.event.inputs.VM_NAME }}VMDisk"
  OSDiskType: "${{ github.event.inputs.OSDiskType }}"
  VM_SIZE: "${{ github.event.inputs.VM_SIZE }}"
  image_version: "${{ github.event.inputs.VERSION_NUMBER }}"
  REGION_CODE: "${{ github.event.inputs.REGION_CODE }}"
  appAsgName : "hij-dev-01-dev-ap-${REGION_CODE}"
  asg_rg : "rg-network-${github.event.inputs.REGION_CODE}-kk"
  asgId : /subscriptions/"${env.subscription_id}"/resourceGroups/"${env.asg_rg}"/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationSecurityGroups/"${env.appAsgName}"
jobs:
  windows-Vm-Creation:
    # Runner Machine where we need to run the steps
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    
       # Check-Out the code from the repository
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
```

I am trying the below command to assign the variables.

location value I am fetching it from the workflow trigger

```
Location: "${{ github.event.inputs.Location}}"

Name 1: "name-02-${env.Location}"

Name 2 : "name-03-git--${env.Location}-01"

NameID: /subscriptions/"${env.subscription_id}"/resourceGroups/"${env.Name1}"/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationSecurityGroups/"${env.Name2}"
```

I am using env because location is assigned in an env variable section

Comment: Show your full workflow please

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski added the workflow file please have a look at it

Comment: And what is wrong exactly there? Do you have a problem with any variables there? Is something not displayed as it should?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski yes if you see in the env sections on the last 3 variables i.e appAsgName ,asg_rg ,asgId  i am trying to call some env values into these env values that where i am facing issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you try to use env variable in the same place where you set them.

I would suggest to use the inputs variable for the last env variables as well, which would look like this:

```yaml
env:
  subscription_id: "${{ github.event.inputs.SUBSCRIPTION }}"
  location: "${{ github.event.inputs.REGION }}"
  VM_NAME: "${{ github.event.inputs.VM_NAME }}"
  ResourceGroupName: "${{ github.event.inputs.ResourceGroupName }}"
  NetworkInterfaceName: "${{ github.event.inputs.VM_NAME }}VMNic"
  OSDiskName: "${{ github.event.inputs.VM_NAME }}VMDisk"
  OSDiskType: "${{ github.event.inputs.OSDiskType }}"
  VM_SIZE: "${{ github.event.inputs.VM_SIZE }}"
  image_version: "${{ github.event.inputs.VERSION_NUMBER }}"
  REGION_CODE: "${{ github.event.inputs.REGION_CODE }}"
  appAsgName : "hij-dev-01-dev-ap-${{ github.event.inputs.REGION_CODE }}"
  asg_rg : "rg-network-${{ github.event.inputs.REGION_CODE }}-kk"
  asgId : "/subscriptions/${{ github.event.inputs.SUBSCRIPTION }}/resourceGroups/rg-network-${{ github.event.inputs.REGION_CODE }}-kk/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationSecurityGroups/hij-dev-01-dev-ap-${{ github.event.inputs.REGION_CODE }}"
```

That way, you won't have a variable composed on the others, but all composed of inputs.